# How to remove all subtitle channels except the first English one with FFmpeg?

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video

I'm not very well versed on FFmpeg, and I've tried to do this many times myself, but I couldn't even figure out the syntax.. So I'm going to ask outwards to people much smarter than myself. I wish to use FFmpeg to remove all non-english options, thereafter deleting them.

After that, deleting all English options except the first indexed one. I couldn't figure that out no matter what I tried, and bashed my head against the wall for about 3 hours trying, with my final attempt being:

```
ffmpeg -i "Episode 01 - Yaha-kui zaShunina.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:s -map 0:m:language:eng -map:0:a:1? -codec copy "copy Episode 01 - Yaha-kui zaShunina.mkv"
```

This was the only one that I got the right syntax for.. and it still didn't quite work. Anybody smarter than myself able to help? Also, I'd prefer to preserve all video, and make sure that they're soft subs over burnt-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is `-map 0:s:m:language:eng`:

`ffmpeg -y -i "Episode 01 - Yaha-kui zaShunina.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s:m:language:eng -codec copy "copy Episode 01 - Yaha-kui zaShunina.mkv"`

The issue is that it is mapping all the english subtitles (not only the first stream). We may execute FFmpeg a second time for keeping only the first english subtitles stream using `-map 0:s:0`:

`ffmpeg -y -i "Episode 01 - Yaha-kui zaShunina.mkv" -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s:0 -codec copy "copy copy Episode 01 - Yaha-kui zaShunina.mkv"`

(I don't know if it's possible to keep only the fist english stream in one command).

---

The following [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/comments/hsr7wu/comment/fyc7amd/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button), shows that for mapping an English audio stream the syntax is `-map 0:a:m:language:eng`.
`0:a` refers the audio stream.
We may replace it to `0:s` for referring the subtitle stream.

---

Testing:

Create synthetic video file with multiple video, audio and subtitle streams (for testing):

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=384x206:rate=1 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=300 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=500 -i in.srt -i in.srt -i in.srt -i in.srt -i in.srt -map:v 0 -map:a 1 -map:a 2 -map:a 3 -map:s 4 -map:s 5 -map:s 6 -map:s 7 -map:s 8 -c:v libx264 -c:a:0 ac3 -ar:0 44100 -c:a:1 ac3 -ar:1 44100 -strict -2 -c:a:2 dca -ar:2 44100 -c:s ass -metadata:s:a:0 language=fra -metadata:s:a:1 language=ger -metadata:s:a:2 language=eng -metadata:s:s:0 language=fra -metadata:s:s:1 language=ger -metadata:s:s:2 language=ger -metadata:s:s:3 language=ger -metadata:s:s:4 language=eng -t 10 input.mkv`

Content of `in.srt` (used for testing):

```
1
00:00:00,0 --> 00:00:01,0
Sec 0 to 1

2
00:00:01,0 --> 00:00:02,0
Sec 1 to 2

3
00:00:02,0 --> 00:00:03,0
Sec 2 to 3

4
00:00:03,0 --> 00:00:04,0
Sec 3 to 4
```

Checking the streams of `input.mkv` using MediaInfo tool:

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
...
Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Language                                 : French
...
Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Language                                 : German
...
Audio #3
ID                                       : 4
Language                                 : English
...
Text #1
ID                                       : 5
Language                                 : French
...
Text #2
ID                                       : 6
Language                                 : German
...
Text #3
Language                                 : English
...
Text #4
Language                                 : German
...
Text #5
ID                                       : 9
Language                                 : English
```

Executing the command for keeping only english subtitles:
`ffmpeg -y -i input.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s:m:language:eng -codec copy tmp_output.mkv`

Using MediaInfo with `tmp_output.mkv` we may see that there are two english subtitles.

Execute FFmpeg once more with `-map 0:s:0`:
`ffmpeg -y -i tmp_output.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a? -map 0:s:0 -codec copy output.mkv`

Checking the streams of output.mkv using MediaInfo tool shows only one english subtitles stream:

```
Text
ID                                       : 5
Language                                 : English
Default                                  : Yes
Forced                                   : No
```

Comment: Many thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Though, sorry to ask one more question, but I do have one -- For the final singular audio track, is there a way that I can name it?

Comment: What  do you mean by "name it"? Do you mean setting the language like `-metadata:s:a language=eng`? Or maybe `-metadata:s:a title="my audio title"`?